# Can my website post to Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a PHP based website which has a post/comment system. Can I add a checkbox to my post function so that if it is checked the post will be published to Facebook as well as my own website at the same time?

I have looked through the docs on facebook and I saw a comment plugin, but it's not really what I am looking for.

I would appreciate a tutorial, links, code, or just general help.

Comment: Please keep the question to the point and refrain from giving background of your work. It is a good practice and helps users to focus on your real problem :)

Comment: Got it! Sorry, I'll remember that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to replicate the auto-posting functionality in the `fb:comments` plugin, the only way to accomplish that is asking the users to install an app. By using the sandboxed `fb:comments` social plugin, Facebook controls the user experience, so users can post to their wall without an install. If you use your own method though, you'll need to require an install (and [`publish_stream` permissions)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

I'd recommend using `fb:comments` if at all possible, since that creates less friction for your users and will be a more familiar experience for them. If you wish to do something with the comment as it's added, you can [subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to the `comment.create` event.

Comment: Well said, +1 for the info. I really don't want to force an install, but I would like them to be able to post to my blog and facebook within the same event. Is there any way you can elaborate on how I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend subscribing to the event, as I just added.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use the Feed Dialog have a look: http://bit.ly/rQWC36
You can launch the dialog if the checkbox is checked, after submit the comments form.
Or may be you can use the OpenGraph API versión of the feed dialog, look for the section: "**Graph API Equivalent**" documentation doesn't sais nothing about permission on using that dialog this way. I hope it helps.

Comment: +1, the feed dialog is a good way to do that, the user will not need to give permissions, but the user will have to fill the post again, there's no way from Facebook to have the post itself pre-filled.

Comment: @bool.dev they say: "Your application can also publish directly to a profile's feed without user interaction, use the corresponding Graph API call".
In other to call the Feed Dialog trough the OpenGraph you will need an Acces Token, to get it you must ask your users to login to your website via Facebook.
I think that a feature like that described by Juan Gonzales requires a Login verificación before render the checkbox, and a Facebook Login as decribed in [Authentication docs](http://bit.ly/vqBhro).

Comment: not necessarily, imho. depends on what user flow Juan wants to go with, if he is fine with users being shown the facebook post pop up, then no need of auth. even he doesn't want that then ofcourse graph api, plus auth is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure of what you are looking for but still [facebook api](http://I%20am%20still%20unsure%20of%20what%20you%20are%20looking%20for%20but%20still%20facebook%20api) is a good place to start off. A part from that, the checkboxes and **automatically** going to facebook that you have referred will be done according to your language/framework which you have not illustrated.